# My wall was painted over a year ago, next door has been banging and now caulking has occured. Whose fault?

Tags: painting

I had my wall painted a year and a half ago and it has been fine. Next door has been using a lump hammer and now caulking has occured. They say it is nothing to do with them but I am worried. Can it be the fault of my decorator or is it their fault?

Comment: What does caulking has occurred mean? And when you say next door, do you mean an adjacent apartment?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need some clarity on what you're describing before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Caullking is used to seal gaps etc, so how has it now "occurred"? Do you mean things have moved and it has become visible?

Comment: I think you mean cracking has occurred? What are the walls made of? What is the neighbor hitting with the lump hammer?

Comment: If the wall looked fine for a year and a half and cracks showed up after the neighbor pounded on the other side if th bath room wall it is safe to say the pounding caused the cracking